# what is this? (unexpected character after line continuation character)

Tags: python

```
for x in range(len(s.body)):
        if s.body[x].pos in list(map(lambda z:z.pos,s.body[x+1:])):
            print(\'Score: \', len(s.body))
            message_box(\'You Lost!\', \'Play again...\')
            s.reset((10,10))
            break
```

It seems fine to me, but i cant seem to find the error.

Comment: A \ character in python is "line continuation character" you should not use it like you did here.

Answer (score 2):

The single quotation mark `'` is written as `\'` in your code (perhaps due to copying?) Simply run

```py
for x in range(len(s.body)):
        if s.body[x].pos in list(map(lambda z:z.pos,s.body[x+1:])):
            print('Score: ', len(s.body))
            message_box('You Lost!', 'Play again...')
            s.reset((10,10))
            break
```

`\` is the "line continuation character" in Python that continues a line to the next line, which is not expected here.

Comment: it worked now i just need to sort out the  intends, thank you